# CSS - How to set height of absolute div same with neighbor image?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I got two DOM elements in (A) relatively positioned `<div>`

One of them is (B) responsive image and the other is (C) absolutely positioned `<div>`

I'd like to **set (C)'s height same with (B)'s height** to align (C)'s content vertically centered in (A)

Here is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/npayu4ez/) code

I'd like to find method which uses **CSS only**, not the javascript.

Comment: `#child-block { height: 100% }` alone seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have given teh `height 100px` and `width 100%`. But the height must be 100% and i give the width 60%. And to get center the div i give left 20%. Because width = 60% left = 20% and right  20% then 60% + 20% + 20% = 100%

**This is the fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/avrkmhfq/1/